# Applications have playback problems of videos from internet

Tags: android, android-intent, video, webview, youtube

After selecting stock videoplayer (`com.android.gallery3d`) or `MX Player` using an [ActionChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER) I get these errors (respectively): `Can't play this video.` or `Can't play this link.`, by running the following code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/v/fyoCXePXQF0&loop=1&playlist=fyoCXePXQF0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1"), "video/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to use this with external video players (MX Player and most importantly the stock player) because such is better than using a WebView which plays only audio – I'm guessing flash (which like all plugins is `@deprecated` as of `API 18`); and HTML5 can make it work and is better anyway even though I don't know how to use either.Youtube displays error `There was a problem with the network [400](…)` by running this:

```
case 2:
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/v/fyoCXePXQF0&loop=1&playlist=fyoCXePXQF0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1")));
    break;
```

As a fallback I would use embedding but it ignores the video options unless `embed` is changed to `v` (which causes the web browsers – including this app's `WebView` – to not display the video too) and also prevents it from playing explaining that:

`This video contains content from (…). It is restricted from playback on certain sites. 
                                   Watch on YouTube`                                     
Maybe the URI can include some data (URL header related?) to prevent this.

Comment: That URL leads to something of MIME type `application/x-shockwave-flash`, not `video/*`. Hence, it is not surprising that apps will fail to handle it properly when you say that the MIME type is `video/*`.

Comment: @CommonsWare How should I improve my question? `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/v/fyoCXePXQF0&loop=1&playlist=fyoCXePXQF0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1"), "video/*");` sets the MIME type to any video file (not `application/x-shockwave-flash`)

Comment: Delete `video/*` and replace it with `application/x-shockwave-flash`. Or, use a URL to an actual video, not a Flash object.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh I get it now, sorry.After replacing `MX Player` opens straightaway after `case 4:` is triggered and shows the same error even for the normal URL ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyoCXePXQF0 ) Maybe I should use the video's direct URL instead but I don't know how to make it play as required. This doesn't play at all (too long URL for comment): http://pastebin.com/NiVCsxAZ

Comment: Other than YouTube itself, I do not know of players that can play from YouTube URLs, but I haven't researched it. Though I am surprised that MX Player accepts `application/x-shockwave-flash` URLs but can't show them.

Comment: @CommonsWare in case you are interested PVSTAR+ (which I don't like) can.I think MX Player can play `application/x-shockwave-flash` but the links need to be of the actual video stream with some HTTP headers which is what –  for example – TubeMate pass on to players to make them (MX Player too) play videos.